# Connect Oracle cloud DB in JAVA using SSH with Local port forward

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ssh, oracle11g

I want to connect to an Oracle db in **JAVA** which hosted in cloud. I have server private key and remote details to connect.

I can establish SSH connection to server with private key authentication and created SSH tunnel. Now using this tunnel, I can connect to remote server and forwarded session to local port.

Now I used below URL to connect Oracle DB,

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:" + local_port_forward + "/service_name", db_user, db_password
```

But it throws below error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Oracle Error: ORA-12650

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/network.101/b10772/asoappa.htm?

Comment: Have you looked at  Oracle DB machine encryption ENCRYPTION_SERVER settings ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919402/io-exception-oracle-error-ora-12650-in-oracle-cloud

Comment: I don't have privilege to access server which Oracle DB installed.
I have only SSH & remote details to connect Oracle DB.

Comment: Please look at the properties that can be passed with the connection. eg:                                                                     props.put("oracle.net.encryption_client", "REQUIRED");
props.put("oracle.net.encryption_types_client", "RC4_40 ");
props.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client","REQUESTED");
props.put("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client ", " MD5 ");

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle server may redirect the client (JDBC thin in your example) to a different port than the listener's port. So doing Oracle database connection over an SSH tunnel isn't possible.