# How to connect RobotFramework with Exadata DB?

Tags: robotframework, exadata

i am trying to connect to an Exadata DB via Robot Framework with cx_Oracle component and not jdbc. My attempts fail miserably.
The configuration i have used is the proper one, meaning username, pwd and host but the error message probably sent by Exa is ORA-12650: No common encryption or data integrity algorithm.

Could you kindly assist me on this? Thnx a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650 in Oracle Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919402/io-exception-oracle-error-ora-12650-in-oracle-cloud)

Comment: What does _"My attempts fail miserably"_ mean? How do they fail? Do you connect to the wrong database? Does it throw an error? Does it cause robot to crash?

Comment: Thnx for responding. No I am not connecting to the wrong database. Neither robot crashes. I receive an error message ORA-12650 No common encryption or data integrity algorithm and of course connection is never established. My  connection string is the following: Connect to database using Custom Params, cx_Oracle, Username,Pwd,Host